# Pessimistic locking fails with ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

I use Spring Data JPA with Hibernate as persistence provider over PostgreSQL. I'm trying to provide pessimistic locking:

```
public interface MediaRepository extends JpaRepository<Media, Long>, MediaRepositoryCustom {
Long countByCreatedBy(User creator);

@Query("select m from Media m where m.id = ?1")
@Lock(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
Media findOneAndLock(Long id);
}
```

I try to call `findOneAndLock` from 2 threads. I expect that if `Thread A` locks object, `Thread B` should wait until the lock is released. But instead `Thread B` throws `org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`.

I'm sure that both threads performs select for update (2 such records in database log).

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior is to not wait. You need to specify the wait period in the `persistence.xml`

```
<properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.lock.timeout" value="1000"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: Whats the value? And the second thread will only wait for the configured time and NOT indefinitely.

Comment: 10000. Again, I catch org.springframework.orm.ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException.

Comment: Does this exception occur immediately or after 10 seconds?

Comment: It occurs immediately and it's stack trace includes call to `findOneAndLock`

Comment: Yes because its a hint and may not be applied always. read [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkjiu.html).

Comment: also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19266015/jpa-pessimistic-lock-attempt-never-times-out)

Comment: I don't understand how that links relate to my problem