# How to set lock timeout in postgres - Hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to set a [`Lock`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33081311/1706545) for the row I'm working on until the next commit:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT value from Table where id=:id")
            .setParameter("id", "123")
            .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
            .setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 10000)
            .getSingleResult();
```

What I thought should happen is that if two threads will try to write to the db at the same time, one thread will reach the update operation before the other, the second thread should wait 10 seconds and then throw [`PessimisticLockException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PessimisticLockException.html).

But instead the thread hangs until the other thread finishes, regardless of the timeout set.

Look at this example :

```
database.createTransaction(transaction -> {
    // Execute the first request to the db, and lock the table
    requestAndLock(transaction);

    // open another transaction, and execute the second request in
    // a different transaction
    database.createTransaction(secondTransaction -> {
        requestAndLock(secondTransaction);
    });

    transaction.commit();
});
```

I expected that in the second request the transaction will wait until the timeout set and then throw the [`PessimisticLockException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/PessimisticLockException.html), but instead it deadlocks forever.

Hibernate generates my request to the db this way :

```
SELECT value from Table where id=123 FOR UPDATE
```

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19850909/1706545) I saw that `Postgres` allows only `SELECT FOR UPDATE NO WAIT` that sets the timeout to 0, but it isn't possible to set a timeout in that way.

Is there any other way that I can use with `Hibernate / JPA`?
Maybe [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20963450/controlling-duration-of-postgresql-lock-waits) is somehow recommended?

Answer (score 9):

Hibernate supports a [bunch of query hints](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/11-jpa-hibernate-query-hints-every-developer-know/). The one you're using sets the timeout for the query, not for the pessimistic lock. The query and the lock are independent of each other, and you need to use the hint shown below.

But before you do that, please be aware, that Hibernate doesn't handle the timeout itself. It only sends it to the database and it depends on the database, if and how it applies it.

To set a timeout for the pessimistic lock, you need to use the `javax.persistence.lock.timeout` hint instead. Here's an example:

```
entityManager.createQuery("SELECT value from Table where id=:id")
        .setParameter("id", "123")
        .setLockMode(LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
        .setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 10000)
        .getSingleResult();
```

Comment: it's was a typo mistake,ive change the question

Comment: It won't work with Postgres... if provide 0 for javax.persistence.lock.timeout... NO_WAIT will trigger but with other values postgres ignores it.

Answer (score 3):

There is the `lock_timeout` parameter that does exactly what you want.

You can set it in `postgresql.conf` or with `ALTER ROLE` or `ALTER DATABASE` per user or per database.

Comment: He wants to lock the row for the specific query only, not the entire database or user

Comment: Is there no way to run an SQL statement from Hibernate? `SET LOCAL lock_timeout = 1000`

Answer (score 3):

I think you could try

```
SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '10s';
SELECT ....;
```

I doubt Hibernate supports this out-of-box. You could try find a way to extend it, not sure if it worth it. Because I guess using locks on a postges database (which is mvcc) is not the smartest option.

You could also do `NO WAIT` and delay-retry several times from your code.

Comment: Watch out! This is only session local settings, see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/config-setting.html For global settings, see my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/74208072/204950

Answer (score 2):

The hint for lock timeout for PostgresSQL doesn't work on PostreSQL 9.6 (`.setHint("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 10000`)

The only solution I found is uncommenting lock_timeout property in postgresql.conf:

```
lock_timeout = 10000            # in milliseconds, 0 is disabled
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who's still looking for a data jpa solution, this is how i managed to do it

1. First i've created a function in postgres

```
CREATE function function_name (some_var bigint)
RETURNS TABLE (id BIGINT, counter bigint, organisation_id bigint) -- here you list all the columns you want to be returned in the select statement
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '5s';
    return query SELECT * from some_table where some_table.id = some_var FOR UPDATE;
END;
$$;
```

2. then in the repository interface i've created a native query that calls the function. This will apply the lock timeout on that particular transaction

```
  @Transactional
  @Query(value = """
      select * from function_name(:id);
      """, nativeQuery = true)
  Optional<SomeTableEntity> findById(Long id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate has refused to do any workaround (no offense), see https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16071, since

> 1. JPA query hints are optional.
> 2. Postgres itself does not support statement-level lock timeouts.

But there is an option to globally configure `lock_timeout` parameter, see https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/lock_timeout/

```sql
ALTER DATABASE name SET lock_timeout=10000;
```

To print current value, use

```sql
show lock_timeout;
```

Comment: And restart the database e.g.: `sudo systemctl restart postgresql`